# Why do I need to reload the page for WordPress to see the new custom field added with jQuery

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery

I added custom meta boxes and dynamically add an image loader button to it. The first image uploader works fine, it is generated by php. But, if I add a new row with an image loader button, then clicking on the button does not open the image loader, but the page is reloaded, at the same time the added new row is saved after refreshing the page and now if I click on the button, the image loader will open and everything will be OK.

This is how it looks in the admin area
[image]

Here is a function that adds a new row with a new image loader button. Found in the function.php file :

```
<script>
var addRow = function () {
    var rowCount = jQuery('#my tr').length;
    var w = "<?php echo $w; ?>";
    var h = "<?php echo $h; ?>";
    var def = "<?php echo $default; ?>";
    var def_id = 614;
    var title = "<?php echo $title; ?>";
    var upload_set_img = "<?php echo $upload_set_img; ?>";
    var html = '';
        html +=  '<tr id="my-row'+rowCount+'"><td><img data-src="' + def + '" src="' + def + '" width="' + w + 'px" height="' + h + 'px" />';
        html += '<div>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="my['+upload_set_img+'][]" id="'+ upload_set_img +rowCount+'" value="'+def_id+'" />';
        html += '<button type="submit" class="upload_image_button button">Upload</button>';
        html += '<button type="submit" class="remove_image_button button">×</button>';
        html += '</div></td>';
        jQuery('#my tbody').append(html);
}
</script>
```

I suspect that WordPress is caching something during page load, and when the page is loaded and I added html using jQuery, it does not see this data, so it does not open the image loader in the newly added row.
But I'm not sure if this is the case and don't know how to fix it. Someone could suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the dynamic new button. Otherwise the DOM/Browser won't know what to do. You need to tell the browser to accept/listen to the newly created button. Otherwise you are triggering a form submit, which will result in a page reload.

Comment: @user3135691 Thank you. But it is still not clear to me how I can do this in practice. Please clarify, are you talking about this action? [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#client-side-code)

Comment: @VladSiy What that user describes is not a WordPress issue. It's how JavaScript and jQuery work. You should ask about it at stackoverflow.com. Mention the comment for context.